# on enum and bitwise operation

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, enumeration

Maybe the question is so simple...

There is an enum definition:

```
enum uop_flags_enum {
  FICOMP        = 0x001,  
  FLCOMP        = 0x002,  
  FFCOMP        = 0x004, 
  FMEM          = 0x008, 
  FLOAD         = 0x010, 
  FSTORE        = 0x020, 
  FCTRL         = 0x040, 
  FCALL         = 0x080,  
  FRET          = 0x100, 
  FCOND         = 0x200  
};
```

Somewhere in the code there is:

```
if (uop->flags & FCTRL)
```

When this condition is true and when it is not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ultimately, this code is checking if a single bit (the FCTRL flag) is turned on in the `uop->flags` variable.

But here's some explanation:

Implicitly, the code `if(X)` checks for X being a "true" value.
For integers, 0 is the only "false" value and everything else is "true".

Therefore your code is equivalent to:

`if (0 != (uop->flags & FCTRL))`

Now, what does that mean?

The `&` operator performs a "bitwise AND", which means each bit of the left-hand-side is ANDed with the corresponding bit on the right-hand-side.

So if we wrote out our two operands in binary:

```
uop->flags      1010 1010  (example)

FCTRL           0100 0000
```

In this example, if you perform an "AND" on each pair of bits, you get the result:

```
result          0000 0000
```

Which evaluates to false, and indeed in that example the `uop->flags` value does not have the FCTRL flag set.

Now here's another example, where the flag **is** set:

```
uop->flags      1110 1010  (example)

FCTRL           0100 0000
```

The corresponding ANDed result:

```
result          0100 0000
```

This result is non-zero, therefore "true", triggering your `if` statement.

Answer (score 5):

This is an enum used to define a number of "flags" for an operation. You can deduce this by the fact that every defined value is an exact power of two, and because of this is represented by a single bit ("flag") of a value.

The advantage of this type of enum is that you can combine as many of the flags as you want by using [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR):

```
uop->flags = FMEM | FLOAD | FRET; // sets the three corresponding flags
```

The condition you give, which uses [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND)

```
uop->flags & FCTRL
```

is true if and only if when the `FCTRL` flag is set, i.e. when the 7th bit of `uop->flags` is set. This is because FCTRL == 0x040 == binary 01000000.

Comment: What should I do if I want to check if FRET is set?

Comment: @mahmood: `if (uop->flags & FRET) { /* FRET is set */ }`

Answer (score 1):

When the bit corresponding to FCTRL (0x040) is set in uop->flags, the condition is true. '&' is a bitwise AND in effect masking all bits but the ones set by FCTRL.

Comment: uop->flags=0x140    =>   is the condition true?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation for more details on bitwise operations.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is true when the bit is set. 0x40 is 1000000, so when the 7th bit in `flags` is set - it will be true.

Answer (score 0):

As the enumerate type is making use of the position of binary digits (i.e. units, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc) and the operation does a logic and. If that bit place is set the value will not be zero (true) otherwise it will be false.

Answer (score 0):

In this case each next enum item is shifted by 1 bit left, so it is legal to check if some flag is set by just checking if `variable & flag == true`. However what if we want to set multi-bit flag pattern ? For example-

```
enum {
     #ifdef __GNUC__ // cool in GCC we can use binary constants
        myFlag = 0b1010
     #else           // otherwise fallback into integral constant mode
        myFlag = 10
     #endif
}
```

when how to check if our variable X has this flag set ? We can't just do
`X & myFlag == true`, because for example `0b1000 & myFlag == true` and `0b0010 & myFlag == true` - but neither 0b1000 nor 0b0010 has our TWO bits set ! For this reason I prefer full checking of bitmask which lets to define multi-bit patterns in enum:

```
#define IS_BIT_MASK_SET(variable,flag) ((variable & flag) == flag)
```

hth!